# Program keeps returning None even though I don't have a definition in it

Tags: python, attributes, mode

I was working on the extra questions for http://learnpythonthehardway.com. After writing a program that opened and read a file, I tried to alter it to add a mode to the open command. But whenever I do that, it returns `None` as well as the file contents.

Here is the code:

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

txt = open(filename, "r")

print "Here's your file %r:" % filename
print txt.read()
print txt.close()

print "Type the filename again:"
file_again = raw_input("> ")

txt_again = open(file_again, "r")

print txt_again.read() 
print txt_again.close()
```

Here is what it prints out:

```
$ python ex15.py filey.txt
Here's your file 'filey.txt':
whatever
None
Type the filename again:
> filey.txt
whatever
None
```

Slashes are between lines.

I found a question explaining that when you don't specify, python returns `None` automatically. However, when I try to use the return command instead, or in addition to print, it requires a definition. When I add a definition I can't get the rest of the code to work. How can I get rid of this `None`?

I'd also appreciate if someone could explain why it shows up with the "r" mode, but not without it.

Answer (score 6):

Every function returns a value in Python. You print out the result of `txt.close()`, which happens to be `None`:

```
print txt.close()
```

Just remove the `print` statement and you should be fine:

```
txt.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it completely.